# Does EF Core Have a Query Que?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core and am trying to figure out why I keep having to increase my SQl timeout setting to make a specific query work. In the process I developed a theory. What if EF has a que of pending requests and when there are too many it just stops working instead of removing older requests from the que. That might explain why increasing timeout time is the only way to keep my browser from showing "err connection closed" when I load pages using a specific query.

I tried posting the query on the Microsoft Q and A website with my problem a couple days ago (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/601858/aspnet-core-app-only-works-for-few-minutes-after-r.html), but as usual Microsoft has not responded with an explanation that specifically explains why their product does not work and how to fix it. The best responses I've gotten are vague suggestions that don't really explain what to do.

For instance, one guy suggest not using ToArray() but doesn't say how the same functionality can be obtained without it. Another guy suggests researching connection resiliency but doesn't say how doing that might solve my problem.

So far I have managed to keep the app running longer without this problem occurring by using LazyCache to cache results of the problem query, but after a couple days the app is having the same problem again. Why is it that Microsoft is quick to tell people not to do something, but never tells people what to do instead?

UPDATE: Since Microsoft requires people to sign into their account to access the above link and nobody here want to sign in here is part of what is posted there. It is an error message from running my app locally

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.
Unknown location

SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.

Show raw exception details
SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b_169_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask<TAntecedentResult, TResult>.InnerInvoke()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<.cctor>b277_0(object obj)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext , bool result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync<TState, TResult>(Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync<TState, TResult>(Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToArrayAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
PostAlmostAnything.SiteServices.PostsService.GetPosts() in PostsService.cs

 }
 public async Task<Posts[]> GetPosts()
 {
         IAppCache cache = new CachingService(CachingService.DefaultCacheProvider) { DefaultCachePolicy = new CacheDefaults { DefaultCacheDurationSeconds = GlobalStatic.SITEPOSTSCACHEDURATION() } };
         string cacheKey = $"GetPosts";
         var cacheobject = await (from post in _context.Posts
                            where post.Active == (bool?)true && post.Adminban == (bool?)false && post.Site == (int?)GlobalStatic.SITENUMBER()
                            select post into pts
                            select new Posts
                            {
                                Postid = pts.Postid,
                                Title = pts.Title,
PostAlmostAnything.SiteServices.PostsService.GetPaginatedResult(int currentPage, int pageSize) in PostsService.cs

                               Sc2url = linkgenerator.subcategory2link($"{pts.CategoryNavigation.Categoryurl}", $"{pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategoryurl}", $"{pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2url}")
                           }
                       }).ToArrayAsync();
     }
     public async Task<List<Posts>> GetPaginatedResult(int currentPage, int pageSize)
 {
     return (await GetPosts()).OrderByDescending((Posts d) => d.Postid).Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
         .ToList();
 }
 public async Task<List<Posts>> GetPaginatedResultByCategoryCity(string catslug, string waslug, string regionslug, string cityslug, int currentPage, int pageSize)
 {
     return (from d in await GetPosts()
PostAlmostAnything.Pages.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in Index.cshtml.cs

     {
         PostService = postService;
     }
     public async Task<PageResult> OnGetAsync()
     {
         Posts = await PostService.GetPaginatedResult(CurrentPage, PageSize);
         return Page();
     }
 }
}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<T>(object taskAsObject)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g_Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>gAwaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>gLogged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g_AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

UPDATE: Here is where I am now as far as trying to paginate the query. I cannot find a way to use an IQueryable and access it with an async task without getting errors for lacking GetAwaiter

````
public IQueryable<Posts> GetPosts(bool active)
        {
            var query = _context.Posts.Where(post => post.Active == active && post.Adminban == (bool?)false && post.Site == GlobalStatic.SITENUMBER());
            return query;
        }
        public IQueryable<Posts> GetPaginatedResult(bool active, int currentPage, int pageSize)
        {
            //IAppCache cache = new CachingService(CachingService.DefaultCacheProvider) { DefaultCachePolicy = new CacheDefaults { DefaultCacheDurationSeconds = GlobalStatic.SITEPOSTSCACHEDURATION() } };
            //string cacheKey = $"GetPosts";
            var cacheobject = GetPosts(active)
                               .Select(pts => new Posts
                               {
                                   Postid = pts.Postid,
                                   Title = pts.Title,
                                   Description = pts.Description,
                                   Dateposted = pts.Dateposted,
                                   Datemodified = pts.Datemodified,
                                   Video = pts.Video,
                                   Videostream = pts.Videostream,
                                   Location = pts.Location,
                                   Tags = pts.Tags,
                                   Cap = pts.Cap,
                                   Titletag = pts.Titletag,
                                   Metatag = pts.Metatag,
                                   Link = pts.Link,
                                   Linkurl = pts.Linkurl,
                                   Category = pts.Category,
                                   Subcategory = pts.Subcategory,
                                   Subcategory2 = pts.Subcategory2,
                                   Worldarea = pts.Worldarea,
                                   Region = pts.Region,
                                   City = pts.City,
                                   Sendemail = pts.Sendemail,
                                   Userid = pts.Userid,
                                   Active = pts.Active,
                                   Adminban = pts.Adminban,
                                   Posturl = linkgenerator.postlink($"{pts.Postid}", $"{pts.Title}"),
                                   Comments = (from cm in pts.Comments
                                               where cm.Active == (bool?)true && cm.Adminblock == (bool?)false
                                               select cm into cmts
                                               select new Comments
                                               {
                                                   Commentid = cmts.Commentid,
                                                   Comment = cmts.Comment,
                                                   Date = cmts.Date,
                                                   Active = cmts.Active,
                                                   Adminblock = cmts.Adminblock,
                                                   Userid = cmts.Userid,
                                                   Post = cmts.Post,
                                                   Ratings = cmts.Ratings.Select((Ratings rts) => new Ratings
                                                   {
                                                       Commentnumber = rts.Commentnumber,
                                                       Rating = rts.Rating
                                                   }).ToArray(),
                                                   Images = cmts.Images.Select((Images imgs) => new Images
                                                   {
                                                       Image = imgs.Image,
                                                       Imagename = imgs.Imagename
                                                   }).ToArray(),
                                                   Likes = cmts.Likes.Select((Likes lks) => new Likes
                                                   {
                                                       Likeid = lks.Likeid,
                                                       Commentid = lks.Commentid
                                                   }).ToArray()
                                               }).ToArray(),
                                   Commentcount = pts.Comments.Where((Comments cm) => cm.Active == (bool?)true && cm.Adminblock == (bool?)false).Count(),
                                   Ratings = (from r in pts.Ratings
                                              where r.CommentnumberNavigation.Active == (bool?)true && r.CommentnumberNavigation.Adminblock == (bool?)false
                                              select r into rtgs
                                              select new Ratings
                                              {
                                                  Ratingid = rtgs.Ratingid,
                                                  Rating = rtgs.Rating,
                                                  Daterated = rtgs.Daterated,
                                                  CommentnumberNavigation = new Comments
                                                  {
                                                      Commentid = rtgs.CommentnumberNavigation.Commentid
                                                  }
                                              }).ToArray(),
                                   Ratingcount = pts.Ratings.Where((Ratings rc) => rc.CommentnumberNavigation.Active == (bool?)true && rc.CommentnumberNavigation.Adminblock == (bool?)false).Count(),
                                   Ratingavg = ratingavg((from rac in pts.Ratings
                                                          where rac.CommentnumberNavigation.Active == (bool?)true && rac.CommentnumberNavigation.Adminblock == (bool?)false
                                                          select rac into ra
                                                          select ra.Rating).Average()),
                                   Images = pts.Images.Select((Images imgs) => new Images
                                   {
                                       Imageid = imgs.Imageid,
                                       Imagename = imgs.Imagename,
                                       Image = imgs.Image,
                                       Imagetype = imgs.Imagetype,
                                       Postid = imgs.Postid,
                                       Comment = imgs.Comment,
                                       Userid = imgs.Userid
                                   }).ToArray(),
                                   Primaryimage = computations.primaryimage((from pic in pts.Images
                                                                             where pic.Imagetype == (int?)1
                                                                             select pic into pi
                                                                             select new Images
                                                                             {
                                                                                 Imageid = pi.Imageid,
                                                                                 Image = pi.Image,
                                                                                 Imagename = pi.Imagename
                                                                             }).DefaultIfEmpty().First()),
                                   Likes = pts.Likes.Select((Likes lks) => new Likes
                                   {
                                       Likeid = lks.Likeid,
                                       Post = lks.Post,
                                       Commentid = lks.Commentid
                                   }).ToArray(),
                                   Likecount = pts.Likes.Where((Likes lc) => lc.Commentid == null).Count(),
                                   WorldareaNavigation = new Worldarea
                                   {
                                       Worldarea1 = pts.WorldareaNavigation.Worldarea1,
                                       Worldareaacronym = pts.WorldareaNavigation.Worldareaacronym,
                                       Wurl = linkgenerator.worldarealink($"{pts.WorldareaNavigation.Worldareaacronym}")
                                   },
                                   RegionNavigation = new Regions
                                   {
                                       Regionname = pts.RegionNavigation.Regionname,
                                       Regionacronym = pts.RegionNavigation.Regionacronym,
                                       Rurl = linkgenerator.regionlink($"{pts.WorldareaNavigation.Worldareaacronym}", $"{pts.RegionNavigation.Regionacronym}")
                                   },
                                   CityNavigation = new Cities
                                   {
                                       City = pts.CityNavigation.City,
                                       Cityacronym = pts.CityNavigation.Cityacronym,
                                       Cityurl = linkgenerator.citylink($"{pts.WorldareaNavigation.Worldareaacronym}", $"{pts.RegionNavigation.Regionacronym}", $"{pts.CityNavigation.Cityacronym}")
                                   },
                                   CategoryNavigation = new Categories
                                   {
                                       Categoryname = pts.CategoryNavigation.Categoryname,
                                       Categorylongname = pts.CategoryNavigation.Categorylongname,
                                       Categorytitle = pts.CategoryNavigation.Categorytitle,
                                       Categorydescription = pts.CategoryNavigation.Categorydescription,
                                       Categorykeywords = pts.CategoryNavigation.Categorykeywords,
                                       Categorymeta = pts.CategoryNavigation.Categorymeta,
                                       Categoryurl = pts.CategoryNavigation.Categoryurl,
                                       Curl = linkgenerator.categorylink($"{pts.CategoryNavigation.Categoryurl}")
                                   },
                                   SubcategoryNavigation = new Subcategories
                                   {
                                       Subcategoryname = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategoryname,
                                       Subcategorylongname = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategorylongname,
                                       Subcategorytitle = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategorytitle,
                                       Subcategorydescription = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategorydescription,
                                       Subcategorymeta = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategorymeta,
                                       Subcategorykeywords = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategorykeywords,
                                       Subcategoryurl = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategoryurl,
                                       Scurl = linkgenerator.subcategorylink($"{pts.CategoryNavigation.Categoryurl}", $"{pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategoryurl}")
                                   },
                                   Subcategory2Navigation = new Subcategory2
                                   {
                                       Subcategory2name = pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2name,
                                       Subcategory2longname = pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2longname,
                                       Subcategory2title = pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2title,
                                       Subcategory2description = pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2description,
                                       Subcategory2meta = pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2meta,
                                       Subcategory2keywords = pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2keywords,
                                       Subcategory2url = pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2url,
                                       Sc2url = linkgenerator.subcategory2link($"{pts.CategoryNavigation.Categoryurl}", $"{pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategoryurl}", $"{pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2url}")
                                   }
                               }).OrderByDescending((Posts d) => d.Postid).Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            //Func<List<Posts>> actionThatWeWantToCache = () => cacheobject;
            //var CachedAdapter = cache.GetOrAdd(cacheKey, actionThatWeWantToCache);
            return cacheobject;
    }```
````

Comment: Maybe put up an example of the types of queries causing your timeouts. 99% of the time performance issues in EF can be addressed by resolving issues that result in more data being queried than necessary more often than necessary, and addressing issues behind the scenes like bad execution plans. (missing indexes or other schema issues resulting in table scans.) Extremely complex queries or ones that are difficult to index (i.e. very open-ended search capabilities) should be queued and run as a separate process where the caller is given back a token to check back with.

Comment: @Steve-Py  I posted a link to the query. I tried adding EnableRetryOnFailure() to my config file as one guy suggested, but it changed nothing as far as I can tell.

Comment: docs.microsoft returns a 404 for that link.

Comment: @StevePy No, but when I try loading it in a different browser I get a login prompt

Comment: @steve-py I just updated the post with an error message I received.

Comment: Your question is full of vagueness and quite ranty, TBH. Why don't you just drily tell what's going on, showing the relevant code and exception messages.

Comment: @GertArnold of course it is ranty. Microsoft tricked me into using .Net Core with demos that could make anyone think that using them as a roadmap is a good idea. The relevant code is already all there. As the comments below the first answer show I still don't know how to change my code to fix the problem. The suggestions so far seem to be on the right track but still don't solve the problem. For instance, using a ViewModel is recommended, but none of the example show how to compute averages in a ViewModel.

Comment: The rant is absolutely irrelevant to the question and only adds noise. You better remove it and. As for the query, it's incredibly large, which may result in a SQL query that's hard to optimize for the query engine or takes a lot of CPU and resources anyway. Timeouts are always very hard to diagnose from a distance. We know nothing of the amount of data or the data model and whether it contains proper indexing. Did you look at the generated SQL at all? Or the query plan?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's your problem with code like this:

```
public async Task<Posts[]> GetPosts()
{
     IAppCache cache = new CachingService(CachingService.DefaultCacheProvider) { DefaultCachePolicy = new CacheDefaults { DefaultCacheDurationSeconds = GlobalStatic.SITEPOSTSCACHEDURATION() } };
     string cacheKey = $"GetPosts";
     var cacheobject = await (from post in _context.Posts
                        where post.Active == (bool?)true && post.Adminban == (bool?)false && post.Site == (int?)GlobalStatic.SITENUMBER()
                        select post into pts
                        select new Posts
                        {
                            Postid = pts.Postid,
                            Title = pts.Title,
                            Sc2url = linkgenerator.subcategory2link($"{pts.CategoryNavigation.Categoryurl}", $"{pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategoryurl}", $"{pts.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2url}")
                       }
                   }).ToArrayAsync();
 }


 public async Task<List<Posts>> GetPaginatedResult(int currentPage, int pageSize)
 {
     return (await GetPosts()).OrderByDescending((Posts d) => d.Postid).Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
     .ToList();
}
```

GetPosts is doing a `ToArray` which will look to materialize your ENTIRE table into entities *BEFORE* doing pagination....  This is also calling C# code like this `linkgenerator(...)` method which will trigger client-side evaluation which is a huge performance no-no since that will also materialize the related entities for all rows. You are then selecting the Post Entities into another class called `Posts` which is either a Post entity instance or a separate DTO/ViewModel in order to capture this link.

This is a common sin when I see developers pursuing DNRY (Do Not Repeat Yourself) to keep common logic in one place, and then employ patterns that treat everything consistently for consistency's sake.

`GetPosts()` is a dangerous method if it returns an array of posts as it would always return everything where the code you are calling wants to optimize for paginated results. This is very common in Generic implementations which force a one-size-fits-all on operations. Some tables will be small enough that a "GetAll" type operation is reasonable safe, however that common method against another table can halt a system for no good reason.

To satisfy DNRY, centralize the common query into a private method that can be called as needed. A public `GetAll()` method for Posts is probably never needed for this entity so I would remove it:

```
private IQueryable<Post> getPosts()
{
    var query = _context.Posts
        .Where(post => post.Active 
            && !post.Adminban 
            && post.Site == GlobalStatic.SITENUMBER());

    return query;
}
```

This method can be called by every method that wants to query across Posts and their related details. This centralizes your common rules around active state, and tenancy. (ownership)

Now to your `GetPaginatedResult` method. Here you're going to want to ensure you are selecting your desired data. I would recommend declaring a ViewModel for the post data given you want to have some computed values.

```
[Serializable]
public class PostViewModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string CategoryUrl { get; set; } 
    public string SubcategoryUrl { get; set; }
    public string Subcategory2Url { get; set; }
    public string Sc2Url
    {
        get { return linkgenerator.subcategory2link(CategoryUrl, SubcategoryUrl, Subcategory2url); }
    }
}
```

Within Linq expressions we want to select all of the raw data from the entity and associated other entities. Where we want to compose/calculate values, we can expose getters in the view model that do this calculation as needed using the raw data.

And for the `GetPaginatedResult` method:

```
public async Task<List<Posts>> GetPaginatedResult(int currentPage, int pageSize)
{
    var posts = await getPosts()
        .Select(x => new PostViewModel
        {
            PostId = x.PostId,
            Title = x.Title,
            CategoryUrl = x.CategoryNavigation.Categoryurl,
            SubcategoryUrl = x.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategoryurl,
            SubcategoryUrl = x.Subcategory2Navigation.Subcategory2url
         }).Skip((currentPage -1) * pageSize)
         .Take(pageSize)
         .ToListAsync();
}
```

Note that the `Select` only selects the raw values from the Post and associated entities. It doesn't attempt to calculate the full link. The view model will take care of that when the property is accessed, such as when it is referenced to compose a view or serialized. You can perform simple computed fields in the Linq expression, but only basic stuff like appending strings together with "+" and some simple functions that EF can translate. Even String.Format (including $"{value}") is off the cards inside a Linq expression fed to EF. It cannot translate that to SQL so it would fall on client-side evaluation and you want to avoid that at all costs. By default with EF Core 2, client-side evaluation was on by default, with EF Core 3.1 onward it is off by default but some teams turn it on. I highly recommend leaving it off as it's a bigger landmine than lazy loading.

That should eliminate your performance issues. This generates a compact SQL statement taking into account the desired pagination and serializes just those results into a view model to return to the view. The core business rules around ownership can be cetralized, and by exposing IQueryable it is left to the consuming code to project or further modify the results (paginate, etc.) to build an efficient query. Don't expose any method that you don't intend to get called. (Like a GetAll())

Edit: It sounds like you are trying to replace:

```
public async Task<Posts[]> GetPosts()
```

with

```
public async IQueryable<Post> GetPosts()
```

This is *not the objective. The objective is to centralize the core logic into a protected method which GetPosts as well as GetPaginatedResult can *both* call rather than having GetPaginatedResult calling GetPosts which is loading *all* data. You also need to address that you *cannot* call linkgenerator from within the `Select` expression without triggering client-side evaluation so the suggestion there is to either define view models for the results, or if you insist on returning the entity models as a view model, adding a non-mapped property for the generated URL.

```
public async Task<Posts[]> GetPosts()
{
    return await _getPosts()
        .Select(pts => new Posts
        {
            Postid = pts.Postid,
            Title = pts.Title,
            CategoryUrl = pts.CategoryNavigation.CategoryUrl,
            SubcategoryUrl = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.SubcategoryUrl,
            Subcategory2Url = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategory2Url
        }).ToArrayAsync();
}

public async Task<List<Posts>> GetPaginatedResult(int currentPage, int pageSize)
{
    return await _getPosts()
        .Select(pts => new Posts
        {
            Postid = pts.Postid,
            Title = pts.Title,
            CategoryUrl = pts.CategoryNavigation.CategoryUrl,
            SubcategoryUrl = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.SubcategoryUrl,
            Subcategory2Url = pts.SubcategoryNavigation.Subcategory2Url
        }).Skip((currentPage-1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Where `_getPosts()` is a new protected `IQueryable` method that centralizes the core rules around your isActive and Site. I put an Underscore before the method name to differentiate it from your public GetPosts() method which is probably called in a number of different places.

You initially want to avoid changing the signature of your **public** methods because this would break anywhere and everywhere else that called this method, where it is better to correct this issue a bit at a time where it is most needed.

Looking at your updated example you don't want to change your public methods to `IQueryable`, leave those as your original return types and just ensure that these methods that call the new `IQueryable` method do their respective `await` with `ToArrayAsync` or `ToListAsync` respectively instead of calling the public GetPosts() method.  The change you will still need to make is to move **ALL** properties where you are calling "linkgenerator" or any similar C# objects/functions into unmapped properties and instead use `Select` to retrieve the raw values these calls will need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238816/discussion-on-answer-by-steve-py-does-ef-core-have-a-query-que).